# openpyxl series name using cell reference

Tags: python, openpyxl

Using python and openpyxl, I'm trying to use a cell reference value as the title of a data series to be put into an XY Scatter plot. I've found a similar solution for the chart title, but I can't get it to work for each series.

Here's line of concern and my best guess as to the solution (Leaves series called "Series1", the default name):

```
series = Series(values, xvalues, title_from_data=False)
series.SeriesLabel = xl.chart.data_source.StrRef( "'Sheet'!C3")
```

Goal is to reference cell value of "C3" on worksheet "Sheet" as the example. I was able to use cell reference for chart title using following code, but series objects don't have a .tx.strRef attribute:

```
c1.title.tx.strRef = xl.chart.data_source.StrRef( "'Sheet'!C1")
```

Full code here:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl as xl
from tkinter import filedialog
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.chart import (
    ScatterChart,
    Reference,
    Series,
)
from openpyxl.drawing.line import LineProperties
from openpyxl.chart.shapes import GraphicalProperties
from openpyxl.chart.trendline import Trendline


sampleData = [["Data1","Title goes here:","Dummy Title"],
              ["CFM", "SP","HP"],
              [5000,0.1,4.0],
              [4500,0.2,4.1],
              [4000,0.3,4.2],
              [3500,0.5,4.2],
              [3000,0.8,4.2],
              [2500,1.1,4.2],
              [2000,1.5,4.2],
              [1500,1.8,4.2],
              [1000,2.0,4.3]
              ]

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

for row in sampleData:
    ws.append(row)

c1 = ScatterChart()
c1.title = "" 
c1.title.tx.strRef = xl.chart.data_source.StrRef( "'Sheet'!C1")
xvalues = Reference(ws, min_col=1, min_row=3, max_row=11)
values = Reference(ws, min_col=2, min_row=2, max_row=11)
series = Series(values, xvalues, title_from_data=False)
series.SeriesLabel = xl.chart.data_source.StrRef( "'Sheet'!C3")

c1.series.append(series)
ws.add_chart(c1, "B15")
wb.save("default.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue a couple of days ago. The following works for me:

instead of:

```
series.SeriesLabel = xl.chart.data_source.StrRef( "'Sheet'!C3")
```

try:

```
series.title = xl.chart.series.SeriesLabel(xl.chart.data_source.StrRef("'Sheet'!C3"))
```